# Insert data from gridview to database ,where row value in rows not equal to 0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to insert data into sql database from Gridview ,where rows values is not equal to 0 using asp.net C#

Below is my Html and C# code with DataTable and image is attached for more clearification I highlighted in red square where value is not equal to 0, will be inserted into the database.

[image]

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="I_ID" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("I_ID")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" Amount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="I_Amt" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("I_Amt")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" Cheque_NO">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="C_NO" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%#Bind("C_NO")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" Cheque_Amount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="C_Amt" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%#Bind("C_Amt")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatus" runat="server" >
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Pending" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Received" Value="2"></asp:ListItem> 
                </asp:DropDownList>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C# Data

```
public partial class cheq : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new System.Data.DataColumn[4] {
                    new System.Data.DataColumn("I_ID", typeof(int)),
                    new System.Data.DataColumn("I_Amt", typeof(int)),
                     new System.Data.DataColumn("C_NO", typeof(int)),
                         new System.Data.DataColumn("C_Amt", typeof(int)),
            });
            dt.Rows.Add(21, 339,500,2);
            dt.Rows.Add(22, 622,400,25);
            dt.Rows.Add(23, 226,474,23);
            dt.Rows.Add(26, 339,0,0);
            dt.Rows.Add(27, 339,0,0);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

    }
```